# Shape collision checking

Tags: collision-detection

I want to check in an shape, wether an point is in it or not.
The shape is descriped with one Array of float vectors.
The vectors are added in clock direction.
The first I can check very easy, the second too, but the third is more difficult.
How I can calculate this ? How this category is in math named, so that I can google ?
[image]

Comment: Search for: point and convex polygon intersection. You will do a series of plane tests to find a distance of point to plane, for each plane of the polygon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called [point in polygon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon). You can find different kinds of algorithms depending on whether your polygons are [convex or concave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_and_concave_polygons).